# How to make a UserControl grow with container (Form)

Tags: c#, winforms

I have an app which consists of a Form that after loading adds two Controls that are descended from UserControl.  The UserControls are sharing the same coordinate space and I alternate which one is visible with BringToFront()/SendToBack().  Basically a poor man's WPF Pages.  The UC's each have a panel that takes up the entire area of the UserControl and the panels contain all of the Buttons, TextBoxes, DataGridView's, etc.

Basically, I'm trying to make the UserControls size with the Form containing them, using either the Dock or Anchor properties, but the problem is the UserControl itself doesn't appear to have these properties, so when I resize the window, the panels containing all the content never get bigger.  I've tried setting both the Anchor and Dock properties of the Panels inside each UserControl to no avail.  I've also tried adding a FlowLayoutPanel to the Form, and then adding the UserControls to that instead of directly to the Form object.  Same result.  Did I screw myself by going with UserControls containing panels?  Any way to fix this?  PS, I'm kinda new to C#/.NET.  Been doing most of my dev work in Java for a while now.

Code ex:

```
//Add the panels
FsLookupPanel = new FSLookupPanel(this, this.LdapConn, this.dbConnect);
MakeResPanel = new MakeReservationPanel(this, this.dbConnect);

this.flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(FsLookupPanel);
this.flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(MakeResPanel);

//this.Controls.Add(FsLookupPanel);
//this.Controls.Add(MakeResPanel);

FsLookupPanel.Visible = true;
MakeResPanel.Visible = false;
```

Comment: where are you looking? you should find them on the parent form when you click on the user control

Comment: Btw, what you see involving .Visible = true / false I just now changed.  I was making both panels visible and simply using BringToFront() and SendToBack() to alternate which was visible because originally Visible=true/false wasn't working for me for some reason.  Now it is.

Comment: What version of the .NET framework are you using? Dock and Anchor are defined on the Control class, from which UserControl derives. So your user controls should have these properties. Also, you might have better luck making them visible/invisible instead of using BringToFront/SendToBack.

Comment: I'm not seeing Anchor or Dock on the UserControl object itself.  Just the panel that each one contains.  Under "Layout", the UserControl has AutoScaleMode, AutoScroll, AutoScrollMargin, AutoScrollMinSize, AutoSize, AutoSizeMode, Location, Margin, MaximumSize, MinimumSize, Padding, and Size

Comment: Hmm.  It's targeting .NET 4.5  Using VS Express 2012.

Comment: I should mention that the UserControls I created are separate from the Form entirely.  They're in the same project, each was created in VS by right-clicking on the project name, and selecting Add -> User Control.  Then the first thing I did with each User Control was set its size to what I wanted and then add a Panel that filled that size (the Panel is set to Anchor top, bottom, left, right)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tryed somthing like this ?

```
FsLookupPanel.Dock = MakeResPanel.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
this.flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(FsLookupPanel);
this.flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(MakeResPanel);
```

this work with framework 3.5 so you should be alright with 4.5

You don't have it when setting the properties via the designer but the property is there. Via code it is working

Comment: Aha!  I think that might have fixed it... I thought it was strange that VS didn't show those properties in the designer view if they were available.  Thanks everyone!!  This is the first time I've ever posted here, and I'm impressed with response time and all of the helpful suggestions.

Comment: @user2461087 yeah it's kinda odd that vs don't know about those properties in designer. If this answer your question you can mark this as answer (litle check top left of this answer)

Comment: Okay, I checked it.  Thanks again.  I'm fiddling with the anchor properties on all of the sub-panels and buttons now.  Hehe.  Fun.